# How to start profile agent in yourkit

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs7JA.png)Unable to run JMeter on your kit profiler. I am running Jmeter on my local machine Is there a way to attach a profiler agent
I am getting an error as profile agent should be started
can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable profiler telemetry for JMeter prior to connecting to it, it can be done via [`-agentpath` Java command line argument](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/intro.html)

So if you launch JMeter as:

```
java -agentpath:c:\path\to\yourkit\yjpagent.dll -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

you should be able to establish the connection. Alternatively you can set `JVM_ARGS` or `JMETER_OPTS` environment variable with the above javaagent setting.

More information:

- [Enabling profiling manually](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/agent.jsp3)
- [Running JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running)

Normally you shouldn't need to profile JMeter itself (assuming that you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide) you should rather connect the profiler to the system under test

Comment: java -agentpath  C:\Program Files\YourKit Java Profiler 2021.3-b233\bin\win64\yjpagent.dll -jar D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\ApacheJMeter       I am getting error as Unrecognized option: -agentpath
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. Thank you

Comment: There should not be space between "-agentpath" and the value, there should be ":". The correct command is java -agentpath:"C:\Program Files\YourKit Java Profiler 2021.3-b233\bin\win64\yjpagent.dll" -jar D:\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\ApacheJMeter